# Why am I getting 'timeout' error on socket.io and self-signed ssl connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, socket.io

I created a nodejs server with https. There is no problem when making a GET request, but when connecting with another nodejs application that works with socket.io-client, I get the error 'WebSocket was closed before the connection was established'. What could be the reason?

server.js:

```js
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../certs/server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../certs/server-crt.pem'),
    ca: [
        fs.readFileSync('../certs/client-ca-crt.pem')
    ],
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const server = https.createServer(options);
const io = new Server(server, { serveClient: false });

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);
});

server.listen({ port: 8443, host: 'localhost' }, () => {
    console.log(server.address());
});
```

client.js:

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import fs from 'fs';

const socket = io('https://server.aaa.com:8443', {
    hostname: 'server.aaa.com',
    transports: ['websocket'],
    key: fs.readFileSync('../certs/client-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../certs/client-crt.pem'),
    ca: [
      fs.readFileSync('../certs/server-ca-crt.pem')
    ],
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    reconnection: false
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socket.id);
});

socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

No problem with that:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const message = { msg: "Hello!" };

const req = https.request(
  {
    host: "server.aaa.com",
    port: 8443,
    key: fs.readFileSync(`../certs/client-key.pem`),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(`../certs/client-crt.pem`),
    ca: [
      fs.readFileSync(`../certs/server-ca-crt.pem`)
    ],
    path: "/",
    method: "GET",
  },
  function(response) {
    let rawData = "";
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      rawData += data;
    });
    response.on("end", function() {
      if (rawData.length > 0) {
        console.log(`Received message: ${rawData}`);
      }
      console.log(`TLS Connection closed!`);
      req.end();
      return;
    });
  }
);
req.on("socket", function(socket) {
  socket.on("secureConnect", function() {
    if (socket.authorized === false) {
      console.log(`SOCKET AUTH FAILED ${socket.authorizationError}`);
    }
    console.log("TLS Connection established successfully!");
  });
  socket.setTimeout(10000);
  socket.on("timeout", function() {
    console.log("TLS Socket Timeout!");
    req.end();
    return;
  });
});
req.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log(`TLS Socket ERROR (${err})`);
  req.end();
  return;
});
req.write(JSON.stringify(message));
```

output:

```
TLS Connection established successfully!
Received message: OK!
TLS Connection closed!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server is listening on localhost, but the client is trying to connect to server.aaa.com. So you have to make the server listen on `server.aaa.com` or `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: thanks but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to the problem.

I need to add the following code for socket.io to use the default socket.io path (/socket.io).

`io.listen(server);`

server.js

```js
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../certs/server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../certs/server-crt.pem'),
    ca: [
        fs.readFileSync('../certs/client-ca-crt.pem')
    ],
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const server = https.createServer(options);

const io = new Server(server);
io.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);
});

server.listen({ port: 9443, host: 'localhost' }, () => {
    console.log(server.address());
});
```